# Accessing the same sql lite db from two applications

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have application and its configuration application.
The configuration is very complicated so I decided to create a separate application for that.
the configuration need to save data to the database and the application will read it.
I saw that the sql lite is local to the application and I can't access the same db from both of them.
Is there way to use the same database ? How ?

Thanks

Comment: Build your own ContentProvider ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develop a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: I'll also point out that you can have multiple launchable activities in the application, all of which would have direct access to the database -- two icons in the launcher even though they came from the same place...

Comment: Thanks, its sound good. do you have any link to example for that. I'm new to Android.

Comment: It's just a matter of setting things up in the manifest -- multiple intent filters.  You'll also want to learn about [task affinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff)

Answer (score 0):

A content provider would be the ideal solution. You can also export the database to the sd card in your config app then import it any time your non config app starts up(or resumes).